# How to post OneToOne field in Django rest-framework using overwrite create method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to override create method to make a post request but I am stuck. Here is my code:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    street_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class Seller(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seller_order',blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sellers = SellerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        seller_validated_data = validated_data.pop('sellers')
        if seller_validated_data:
            seller_obj = Seller.objects.create(order=order)
            seller_obj.first_name = seller_validated_data.get('first_name')
            seller_obj.middle_name = seller_validated_data.get('middle_name')
            seller_obj.last_name = seller_validated_data.get('last_name')
        order.save()
        return order
```

The JSON in Postman I am sending is:

```
{
    "street_number":11,
    "street_name":"dfd",
    "seller":{
        "first_name":"kk",
        "last_name":"dfdf"
    }
}
```

But I am unable to create seller object with a relation of order.