# Django OneToOne relationship - how to serialize it?

Tags: django, serialization, one-to-one

Simple example student and employee class, I want to serialize it like below and it should be OneToOne relationship:

```
{
  "college": "string",
  "year": "string",
  "is_with_college": true,
  "employee": {
    "full_name": "string",
    "email_id": "user@example.com",
    "mobile_no": "string",
    "is_job_ready": true,
    "type": "string",
    "location_preference": "string"
  }
}
```

models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=11)
    is_job_ready=models.BooleanField(False)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location_preference=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Student(models.Model):
    college=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_with_college=models.BooleanField()
    employee=models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('full_name', 'email_id', 'mobile_no', 'is_job_ready', 'type', 'location_preference')

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('college', 'year', 'is_with_college', 'employee')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        employee_data = validated_data.pop('employee')
        if employee_data:
            student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
            Employee.objects.create(student=student, **employee_data)
        return student
```

views:

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to change a few things, still have different errors. I'm sure that it's simple and I'm missing something..
At this moment I have:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: rest_student.employee_id
```

Answer:
[OneToOne Relationship serializer](https://www.coder.work/article/2417517)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548337/serialize-objects-with-one-to-one-relationship-django/30552382) answer.

1. Change `employee = EmployeeSerializer(many=False)` to `employee = EmployeeSerializer(read_only=True)`.
2. To retrieve all students or employee you don't need to add `def create(self, validated_data):`. This is required for updating/creating nested objects.

Comment: Yes, I did,
so first thing I have to add the on_delete=models.CASCADE to the employee=models.OneToOneField.

And when I'm trying to post data i got:
"FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

Comment: 1. `on_delete=models.CASCADE` is not related to create/retrieve, it's only play game when you delete object.

2.  my answer is only for `retrieve` API. To be able to create/edit your model structure with one API call, please check this article: https://django.cowhite.com/blog/create-and-update-django-rest-framework-nested-serializers/

Comment: 1. Yes, you're right.
2. I have done something like in this article some time ago. I have added it above.
But still have same problem with OnToOne relation and post some data like I mentioned above.

Comment: Where do you get this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: rest_student.employee_id`? In `EmployeeViewSet` or `StudentViewSet`, what is the method: POST, PUT?

Comment: Maybe I should just ask how to build serializer for my two models, Employee and Student (OneToOne relationship). I just want to use e.g. postman to POST/GET data.
So I'm sure that I have to overwrite "create" method in StudentSerializer - cause django not support nested serializers. Example of json which I want to use to post data I have added in the first post. 
I think we have gone into too much details.

Comment: The same problem without answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324443/how-to-post-onetoone-field-in-django-rest-framework-using-overwrite-create-metho/64833286#64833286

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for my question :)
[OneToOne Relationship serializer](https://www.coder.work/article/2417517)